# Typescript instanceof operator fails

Tags: angular, typescript

I am writing some inheritance code in an Angular 2 app:

reportColumnSet.ts:

```
import { Equatable } from './../../core/equatable';

export abstract class ReportColumnSet implements Equatable<ReportColumnSet> {

    constructor(public name: string) {
    }

    public abstract equals(other: ReportColumnSet): boolean;
}
```

reportNumberColumnSet.ts:

```
import { ReportColumnSet } from './reportColumnSet';

export class ReportNumberColumnSet extends ReportColumnSet {

    constructor(public name: string) {

        super(name);
    }

    public equals(other: ReportColumnSet): boolean {

        ...
    }
}
```

reportColumnSets.service.ts:

```
...    
import { ReportColumnSet, } from './reportColumnSet';
import { ReportNumberColumnSet } from './reportNumberColumnSet';

@Injectable()
export class ReportColumnSetsService {

    public getReportColumnSets(): Observable<Array<ReportColumnSet>> {

        const actual = new ReportNumberColumnSet('Actual');
        ...

        return Observable.of([actual, ...]);
    }
}
```

Then in a calling method:

```
import { ReportNumberColumnSet } from './../columnsets/reportNumberColumnSet';
...
const columnSetsService = new ReportColumnSetsService();

return Observable.forkJoin(columnSetsService.getReportColumnSets(), ...)
    .map(results => {

     const columnSets = results[0];
     var t = columnSets[0] instanceof ReportNumberColumnSet;
     ...
});
```

**t is false!, but even in the (Visual Studio) debugger it confirms columnSets[0] is an Object(ReportNumberColumnSet) and all the __proto__ looks fine.**

(... is where I have removed some irrelevant code)

I have tried many variations and debugging, pulling my hair out on this one!

Could it be something in System js?

The raw javascript comes out looking like this:

```
var reportNumberColumnSet_1 = require('./reportNumberColumnSet');
...
var actual = new reportNumberColumnSet_1.ReportNumberColumnSet('Actual');
```

Comment: You can use a workaround (ugly but working) that consists on getting the constructor function name and compare it: `var t = columnSets[0].constructor.name === 'ReportNumberColumnSet';` I don't say that as an answer because it's just a workaround, not a way to fix your problem.

Comment: @Supamiu Thanks! It does do what I need to, but as you say not ideal. I still am baffled as to why the `instanceof` does not work.